# How to add a value to nested list in json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

### I have a json variable looks like this

json_data=

```
[
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chini.n@example.com"
    }
]
```

would like to add aks9100 to the collections 
expected result should be looks like this

```
[
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098",
                    "aks9100"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chini.n@example.com"
    }
]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick non-dynamic way to do this:

```
import json

json_path = '/Path/To/File.json'
# Open and read file
with open(json_path, 'r') as fin:
    json_data = json.load(fin)

# Open and write to file
with open(json_path, 'w') as fout:
    # Add str to nested list
    json_data[0]['permissions'][0]['collections'].append("aks9100")
    # Use write() and dumps() to maintain the json format
    fout.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

In the above I am assuming you need to update a json file. In the json data you have a list with a nested dictionary and another list nested in that dictionary. `[0]` gets the first item in the list and the dictionary keys return their respective values.

Answer (score 0):

To add `"aks9100"` to this specific `json` variable you would need to use the following code:

```
import json

json_data[0]['permissions'][0]['collections'].append("aks9100")
```